# Custom page-size names in Latex

Tags: geometry, paper-size

I was wondering if it is possible to "extend" existing page sizes in

`\documentclass{book}`

something like

- `\documentclass[crownpage]{document}`
- `documentclass[demypage]{document}`
- ...

If it is possible, please enlighten. The idea is to create a list of all popular book sizes that are printed here locally and make them available systemwide.

I have read that one can use the `geometry` package and define page sizes (and in turn these definitions can reside in their "own" packages respectively. Something like `\usepackage[crownpage]` (assuming that `crownpage.sty` resides in LaTeX' path (?).

But I was thinking if what I intend to do is plausible.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am new to TeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I guess you mean `\documentclass`? What do you mean by popular book sizes that are printed here? Do you want to know the paper size options of the class `book`? Do you want to add new ones? I would not tweak around in the documentclass but do your settings in the preamble. But please clarify a bit better, what you really want to achieve and what a crownpage is. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the `octavo` package.

Comment: sorry for the type, yes it should have been `\documentclass`. And as for "printed" here, most publishers prefer "octavo" sizes mentioned by  Thérèse `octavo`. A4, and ISO sizes are "accepted" but frowned; for what reason, I am yet to know. As for `crownsize`, `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octavo` should give an overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
% mypapersizes.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypapersizes}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\define@choicekey+{mypapersizes.sty}{papersize}[\mypapersizes@choice\ic]{crown, demy}{%
\ifcase\ic\relax
%crown
  \gdef\mypapersizeswidth{381mm}%
  \gdef\mypapersizesheight{508mm}%
\or
%demy
  \gdef\mypapersizeswidth{445mm}%
  \gdef\mypapersizesheight{572mm}%
\fi}{\PackageWarning{choice \mypapersizes@choice choice \ic}}

\ExecuteOptionsX{papersize=a4paper}
\ProcessOptionsX

\@ifundefined{mypapersizeswidth}{%
  \RequirePackage[\mypapersizes@choice]{geometry}%
  }{%
  \RequirePackage[paperwidth=\mypapersizeswidth, paperheight=\mypapersizesheight]{geometry}%
  }

\endinput
```

Then you can say, for example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[papersize=demy]{mypapersizes}

\begin{document}

abc

\end{document}
```

- The default is for A4.
- If you specify e.g. `letterpaper`, it will work by passing the value onto `geometry`. (It will also do this if you specify `ratcatcher` but `geometry` will obviously complain in that case.)
- Loading `mypapersizes` will override any class option and you should not pass a paper size to the class to avoid confusion.
- If you need to specify additional options for `geometry`, use `\geometry{}` after `\usepackage{mypapersizes}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot- this will help in defining 'non-standard' paper sizes, used for things like souvenirs etc.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the memoir class (an enhanced book/report class) which has many paper size options:

---- 12 for metric paper sizes from a6paper (148 by 105 mm) to msmallroyalvopaper (234 by 156 mm);

--- 8 for US paper sizes from dbillpaper (7 by 3 in) to broadsheetpaper (22 by 17 in)

--- 13 for British paper sizes from pottvopaper (6.25 by 4 in) to imperialvopaper (11 by 7.5 in)

It also includes methods for defining your own paper size.